# Using custom controls with Chewie Video Player on Flutter

Tags: flutter

The documentation at https://pub.dev/documentation/chewie/latest/chewie/ChewieController/customControls.html dont'said much to me...

and I am not capable to find some example on google.

```
  customControls: Widget build(BuildContext context) => {

  },
```

So, how to write custom controls using Chewie ? The attempt above is not the correct approach. This throw me an error :

```
The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic> Function(BuildContext)' 
can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
{Widget customControls}

Defines customised controls. Check [MaterialControls] or [CupertinoControls] for reference.
```